# Error Converting UNIX time to Date in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm using "SQL Server" for Power BI as a source of data. The problem is to convert this back to date on Power BI side.

[image: Unixtimestamp]
[image: Custom Column]

I’m getting the following message:
[image: Error Column]
[image]

Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value " 1205751600" to type Number.
Details:
   Value= 1205751600
    Type=Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a space at the front of the string: `" 1205751600"`. The value should be trimmed first, eg with Text.Trim or Text.TrimStart

Comment: I did Text.trim at the column [WO_Start], but getting same error message

Comment: @AlfMiolan post the error message. Preferably, post the *text* not the screenshot, and the M query, not just the steps

Comment: @AlfMiolan BTW Unix timestamps are in *milliseconds*. You need to divide the number by 1000 before passing it to #duration. Ideally, you should change the type of the `WO_START` column *before* you try to convert it to a duration. Right now you are passing a string to `#duration` which will try to convert it to a number implicitly. You can't even inspect what value will be used unless an error is thrown

Comment: let
    Source = Sql.Database("SAMPLEDATA", "schedwin"),
    schedwin_WO = Source{[Schema="schedwin",Item="WO"]}[Data],
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(schedwin_WO,{{"WO_START", Text.Trim, type text}, {"WO_END", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Trimmed Text", "DateTimeValue", each #datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)+#duration(0,0,0,[WO_START]/1000)),
    #"   10275" = #"Added Custom"{[SEQNUM="   10275"]}[DateTimeValue]
in
    #"   10275"